# How to remove a css class for any wordpress page

Tags: plugins, php, pages, css, html

I need to remove a class for a wordpress page without using javascript, can it be done with php? or any wordpress function?.
the thing is the following: I'm using a plugin and this plugin uses a class wich is damaging the styles of the inner tags inside it, so I need to remove that class without touching the plugin.

I was looking here for a solution but I couldn't find this, looks impossible to me that nobody was made this question.

Comment: What element is the class being added to? What is the class name?

Comment: `<p class="form-row ">*****content****</p>` something like this

Comment: The next step would be to search the plugins for `form-row` to see how this class and other markup are being added. It's possible that there is a filter that could be removed. It would help if you could edit your question and add the code from the plugin.

Comment: is woocommerce plugin and it adds this classes on it's forms

Comment: You'll likely need to leverage the template hierarchy and add the modified templates to your theme. There are many templates, so it might be easier to address the issue via CSS.

Comment: You probably have your own class called "form-row" which is causing a conflict? I reckon change your class and you're set but hard to tell without seeing your code. I found this reference that might help: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/ You can make edits in functions.php for how woocommerce works.